# Metal Shading Language - FragCoord equivalent?

Tags: glsl, metal, shading, metalkit

I tried to translate [this shadertoy scene](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/llt3R4) into `Metal Kernel`. In shadertoy code:

```
void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
{
    vec3 dir = rayDirection(45.0, iResolution.xy, fragCoord);
    ...
}
```

in `OpenGL` case, we need to send `iResolution` from the `glfw` window. And `fragCoord` will be `gl_FragCoord` from `Fragment Shader`.

I have this in `metal` file:

```
kernel void compute(texture2d<float, access::write> output [[texture(0)]],
                    uint2 gid [[thread_position_in_grid]]) {
    int width = output.get_width();
    int height = output.get_height();
    ....
}
```

So I can get my `iResolution` from the `width` and `height`. But I am not sure how to get `gl_FragCoord`.

Do `Metal_stdlib` have something equivalent to `gl_FragCoord`? Or if I have to calculate, How can I get obtain the same value?

Comment: Provided you're dispatching a single grid that's exactly the same size as the output texture, one equivalent to `gl_FragCoord` is `float2(gid) / float2(width, height)`.

Comment: Also, this seems like it's maybe a better match for an actual fragment function in a render pass, rather than a compute function. In that case, the fragment coordinate would be an input variable or `stage_in` struct field marked with `[[position]]`.

Comment: @warrenm Any example code how to do that? Let say my screen resolution is float(800/600), How do I divide the 'thread groups' or 'thread groups count'?

Comment: I may have misunderstood. If you're looking for the "fragment" position in window coordinates (as `gl_FragCoord` is), that's just `float2(gid)`, which ranges from (0, 0) to (width, height) (again, provided your grid dimensions (the product of your threadgroup size and threadgroup count) exactly match the destination texture.

Comment: @warrenm Can you give example by what do you mean by grid dimension exactly match the destination texture? I vaguely get the idea. With example I think I can see it clearer.

Comment: Ok it works. I just replace it with `float2(gid)` and I get what I want. @warrenm can you make it into answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for the "fragment" position in window coordinates (as `gl_FragCoord` is), you can use `float2(gid)`, which ranges from (0, 0) to (width, height). This is only the case if your grid dimensions (the product of your threadgroup size and threadgroup count) exactly match the dimensions of the destination texture.